# Contour integral with path being the bottom half of circle followed by a line segment

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, parametrization

Calculate $$\int_\gamma \sin^2(z)\cos(z) dz,$$ where $\gamma$ is the path from $3\pi$ to $i$ consisting of the following two pieces: The bottom half of the circle $|z-2\pi| = \pi$ followed by the line segment from $3\pi$ to $i$.

---

I can't seem to get the right answer. I'm guessing I'm going wrong with parameterize $\gamma$.

My attempt at the parameterization:

$\gamma=\gamma_1 + \gamma_2$ where
$$\gamma_1=3\pi e^{-it}, t \in [\pi,2\pi]$$
$$\gamma_2=-3\pi t+it+3\pi, t \in [0,1]$$
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sin^2(z)\,\cos(z)=\left(\frac{1}{3}\sin^3(z)\right)'
$$
and hence
$$
\int_\gamma \sin^2(z)\,\cos(z)\,dz=\int_{3\pi}^i \sin^2(z)\,\cos(z)\,dz
=\frac{1}{3}\sin^3(i)-\frac{1}{3}\sin^3(3\pi)=\cdots
$$